# Checking open parenthesis close parenthesis in c#

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

I am creating a compiler.

When I write input code for my compiler, if there is a missing parenthesis, the compiler should show an error. For that I use this code:

```
Stack<int> openingbraces = new Stack<int>();
string output = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < MELEdtior.Length; i++)
{
    if (MELEdtior[i] == '{')
    {
        openingbraces.Push(i);
        output="close braces missing";
    }
    else if (MELEdtior[i] == '}')
    {
        openingbraces.Push(i);
        output = "Open Braces missing";
    }   
}
if(openingbraces.Count==2)
{
    output = "Build Successfull";
}
else
{
    output = "brace missing";
}`
```

When I give simple input like `function{}` it works perfectly. But my input is:

```
{global gHCIRCIN = OBSNOW("Head circumf")}
{IF gHCIRCCM <> "" AND HeadCircsDifferrev()  THEN
OBSNOW("Head circumf",str(rnd(ConvertCMtoIN(gHCIRCCM),2)))  ELSE "" ENDIF }
```

Here my compiler should check the correctness of all parentheses, and show an error message.

My idea to achieve this is to separate opening and closing parentheses first and then pair them, if any pair is missing, my compiler should throw an error message. How can I implement this?

Comment: Note that it gets quite complex quickly: `OBSNOW("{")` the `{` inside the quotes shouldn't count.

Comment: What you basically want to do is increase the count when you encounter an opening brace (that is not within a comment/quotes) and decrease when you encounter a valid closing brace. If you ever drop below 0 count, that means an extra closing brace. If you find at the end that you have a count of above 0, it means that you have a missing closing bracket.

Comment: @xanatos, this complexity is quite easy to resolve: In my answer I replace the text between qoute chars using RegEx...

Comment: If you desing your compiler completely like that you are entering a world of pain. You need to build something called an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) from your input. Preferably you should also [tokenize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(lexical_analysis)) the input first. Also consider using a parser generator.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to detect mismatched brackets as its own step? Your parser should be the one that detects that kind of error (as well as all the other possible syntax errors).

Comment: What exactly you're using for parsing your language? If it's a simple recursive descent parsing, you can add a toplevel statement rule `}` leading to an appropriate error message. Same on an expression level for `)` and `]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a mini program solving the problem. Based on o_weisman's comment.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        int currentOpenBracketNum = 0;
        string message = "Brackets OK";
        string input = @"{globa} }{IF gHCIRCCM <> """" AND HeadCircsDifferrev() THEN OBSNOW(""Head circumf"",str(rnd(ConvertCMtoIN(gHCIRCCM),2))) ELSE """" ENDIF }";

        foreach (char c in input) {
            if (c.Equals('{')) currentOpenBracketNum++;
            else if (c.Equals('}')) {
                if (currentOpenBracketNum > 0) {
                    currentOpenBracketNum--;
                } else {
                    message = "Missing open bracket";
                }
            }
        }

        if (currentOpenBracketNum > 0) {
            message = "Missing close bracket";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Console.ReadKey(); // suspend screen
    }
}
```

**Note:** You could track if you are within " characters and exclude counting of those which is considered as string, if you want to solve the coming issue what xanatos is pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problems with brackets *within* quoted area, I would just use RegEx to replace them. Then you can count the signs:

```
char quoteChar = '"';
string s1 = "{global gHCIRCIN = OBSNOW(\"Head circumf\")} {IF gHCIRCCM <> \"\" AND HeadCircsDifferrev() THEN OBSNOW(\"Head circumf\",str(rnd(ConvertCMtoIN(gHCIRCCM),2))) ELSE \"\" ENDIF }";
string s2 = Regex.Replace(s1, quoteChar + ".*?" + quoteChar, "This_was_quoted");
int countOpening = s2.Count(c => c == '{');
int countClosing = s2.Count(c => c == '}');
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("There are {0} opening and {1} closing }}-signs.", countOpening, countClosing));
```